# Word or phrase for a woman who shows up at events in gaudy outfits, garish make-up, and excessive jewelry?

Tags: phrases, slang, pejorative-language, colloquialisms

Such person is usually - but not necessarily - upper-middle class.

I'm looking for a noun or a noun-phrase but the words I've found so far (unpolished, inelegant, gauche, etc.) are adjectives and/or don't fit what I'm looking for.

EDIT

This noun or noun-phrase...

- is more likely to be used by women when gossiping. ("Did you see that .... at the meeting yesterday?  Yeah, I did. Some people just don't know how ridiculous they can get.)
- isn't related to promiscuity or prostitution.

If the woman is a socialite, her picture will be displayed in newspapers and magazines and she will be a laughingstock..

Comment: One such person was Rebecca Mark, former division CEO of Enron, who showed up at a company function on a motorcyle in leather jackets and pants. I didn't know at the time that Enron was fraudulent, but I did avoid the stock because "this is the woman you don't want your son to date."

Comment: @TomAu And can't you remember what the mídia called her at the time?

Comment: I believe the media reference to her was "Mark the Shark." My "take" (off) on this was: "Oh the shark has, pretty teeth dear, and SHE shows them pearly white." (Weill).

Comment: When you find the word for that, find the one for a **man** who .., as well. Otherwise no fair.

Comment: I'm not sure there really is a word for this in English (at least not a gender specific word). Gender specific words that are *sort of* like what you're saying would be things like "slut", "prostitute", or "whore" but those carry additional meaning that you don't really intend.  As far as gender neutral adjectives go you've got: "nouveau riche" (which emphasizes the upper-middle class thing you mentioned), "ostentatious", "flashy", "showy", "garish", "classless", "pretentious", "gaudy", "pompous".

Comment: @JoeRounceville Why don't you answer the question?  "No, there isn't such slangword or phrase" is an answer too.

Comment: @TomAu I see, after Mc the knife.

Comment: Ms. Mark had her (male) number two "in tow" (the reverse of the usual), and similarly dressed, which "evens" things up. Not to mention the baby elephant.

Comment: "Dolly Parton" or "Bjork", or whoever your peers would reference.

Comment: You might consider _fashionista_. http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-fashionista.htm

Comment: "*Overdressed*" is the general term.  Not sure of any gender specific equivalent.

Comment: This is gender neutral, and is connected to the french phrase "nouveau riche" already supplied above; but I always hear the phrase "new money" applied to those who have wealth, but don't wear it with any sort of class.

Comment: Just plain 'tacky'.

Comment: What's wrong with an adjective? If it's for poetry, just reorder and reword to fit the meter and syntax.

Comment: @CarSmack I have reasons not to.

Comment: @Mari-LouA what would you say about "classy-hoochie" ?  [The Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/) gives this definition: "A classy hoochie is a high-class woman dressed up in a slutty way".  That would fit as an answer, but I don't know how many native speakers ever heard of it.

Comment: I'd consider it to be an inflammatory and mildly offensive term on the same par as *slut*, *trash*, and *tart*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's often been said that beauty is in the eye of the beholder. What one person finds  trashy, slutty, tarty, cheap or tacky-looking in a woman; another sees a woman who oozes self-confidence, style, glamour and sex-appeal.

A woman who has put on a *gaudy outfit* could be described as being [dressed to the nines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_the_nines); [gussied](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gussy+up), [fancied](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fancy%20up) or [dolled up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doll+up?show=0&t=1412636917); [sassy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sassy);  and looking to have fun. If she is dressed provocatively (*gaudy outfits*), wears expensive cosmetics (*garish makeup*), and prefers costume jewelry (*excessive jewelry*) to that of gold and platinum, she is said to be [dressed to kill](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dressed%20to%20kill).

She can be called a *man-eater*; a *seductress*; a *flirt*; a *femme fatale* or just a *socialite*

> [Socialite](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Socialite)
>   She lives in a paradise of a mansion, usually in California, or a
>   penthouse in Manhattan. **You might find her hanging out at various
>   social events**, with a glass of champagne in her hand. Often she
>   doesn't have a job, but sometimes she can be working in a high-end
>   job, such as that of a celebrity publicist, which nets her a very high
>   salary. (...) Can also be prone to **Conspicuous Consumption**, **especially jewels**, **fancy dresses**, and furs.

Alternatively, if she is young and has recently come into money she might be termed as

> [Nouveau Riche](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NouveauRiche)
>   The Nouveau Riche are characterized as **rude and tasteless**, and
>   frequently contrasted with the refined manners of aristocratic Old
>   Money characters. (...) If American, expect them to be Hollywood California people with bleach-blonde Valley Girl daughters, slovenly white trash who won either the lottery or a big-time settlement ... If black, expect a flashy character from a Glam Rap video. (...) Common accessories for this class include **fur coats**, **gaudy jewelry**, obnoxiously color-coordinated suits, and gold teeth.

Source: TV Tropes

Comment: Yes, this answer addresses everything! Do you think _fashionista_ should be mentioned too?

Comment: @ermanen well... that depends. Does she follow the latest trends in fashion? Is she obsessed with fashion accessories; handbags, sunglasses, shoes etc. The OP doesn't mention this.

Comment: I wish you could join the two answers.

Comment: @user463240  I decided  to give a different answer because so many American users were unfamiliar with *mutton dressed as lamb* and it is heavily connected to age, it would be a totally inappropriate term for a 20-year-old.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ok. Great answers anyway.

Comment: Can you say "His wife looked like a "nouveau riche..."  even if the person has always been rich? In this case I'm not saying she is a "nouveau riche" but that she looks like one.

Comment: [she acted like a typical nouveau riche](http://books.google.it/books?id=Z5pL0GvBn1kC&pg=PT134&lpg=PT134&dq=she+acted+like+a+nouveau+riche&source=bl&ots=M5Au6qW-NH&sig=UiJaL85apL3TwxfOMxq4c5GH1ys&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2xw0VKThHeTV7gauvoGwDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=nouveau%20riche&f=false)

Answer (score 10):

If the lady in question is well past her forties, and used to be a highly attractive and courted woman in the past, she might dress provocatively and wear heavy makeup in order to recapture her former glory. Such a woman is often derogatorily called **[mutton dressed (up) as lamb.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mutton+dressed+as+lamb)** in British English.

> an offensive way of saying that a woman is dressed in a style that is
>   more suitable for a much younger woman

Comment: As a native English speaker for 40+ years, I would have absolutely no clue what you meant if you said "mutton dressed as lamb."  My impression would be that this was some obscure Britishism.

Comment: @JoeRounceville I wasn't aware that it's exclusively a British English idiom but I can assure you it is very well-known. Nothing obscure about it in the slightest. http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/mutton-dressed-as-lamb.html

Comment: mutton = old sheep. lamb = young sheep. Instant understanding despite having never heard the phrase before.

Comment: Yes, but how many Americans know what (a)  mutton is? Instant non-communication.

Comment: Mutton is a rarely used word in the USA.  You *might* hear it from time to time in New England, spoken by very elderly sheep herders, or in nursery rhymes... or in reference to some man's sideburns. I mean, I could figure out what you meant, but it certainly isn't a familiar idiom to most people in the USA.

Comment: -1 just because it's (IMO) horribly offensive.

Comment: @ChrisW I agree that the idiom is offensive but I did mention that, and the OP is looking for a derogatory term, not a compliment.

Comment: I agree. I downvoted it only because I find it so offensive that I cannot foresee using it, i.e. it's unusable.

Comment: @ChrisW there are far more offensive terms that I can think of to describe a woman who is trying "too hard", I'm sure you're well aware of them yourself. At least this expression is not vulgar or obscene.

Comment: This term comments on a person's age as much as their dress sense: on whether you find them sexually attractive, whether they're a dish to your taste. It's sexist, ageist, tactless; maybe archaic too. Unusable. :-)

Comment: @ChrisW I agree with everything but it is never archaic, anyone who's British will know this phrase.

Comment: Interesting - for the specific scenario that Mari-Lou describes, "mutton dressed as lamp" would not be an unusual phrase in the UK.  Unkind, certainly, but neither archaic nor so offensive as not to be used.  Sexist and ageist are trickier, as it would often tend to be used by the lady's own age and gender group...

Comment: As a native English (US) speaker of 35 years, I must say I had no idea what "mutton dressed as lamb" meant either.

Answer (score 7):

The noun *[show-off](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/show-off_2)* refers to a person who likes to show off. The adjective *[ostentatious](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/ostentatious)* means showing off your money or possessions to make others notice.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I'm looking for a noun or NP.

Comment: Perhaps a reference or quote showing how "show off" is used in a sentence.

Comment: "Show-off" is a common name in US English for the OP's description.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez, but a show-off does not *necessarily* have anything to do with the description of the OP. One can be a show-off without the gaudiness, garishness and excessiveness in appearance.

Comment: You're right @CarSmack, the gaudiness is just the outer trappings of a "show-off".

Comment: @Kristina Lopez : Gaudiness in dress and appearance has no intrinsic relation to a show-off. A show-off could be all tarted up, but that is totally optional and has nothing to do with the definition of a show-off.

Comment: @CarSmack, in my opinion, gaudiness in dress and appearance are one of many manifestations of a show-off and most certainly has an intrinsic relation to the definition...in this case, the dictionary link provided by Jasper: "a person who shows off (behaves in a way intended to attract attention that other people often find annoying)".

Comment: @KristinaLopez Even the dictionary link (definition) that you cite mentions nothing about clothes or appearance! A show-off is one who *does stuff* to get attention. That much we agree on. What you are saying is that all show-offs *dress* in a way that attracts attention. I, and the dictionary definition, disagree.

Comment: Are you intentionally trolling, @CarSmack? :-)  Where did I say that all show-offs dress in a way that attract attention?  If dressing gaudily draws attention to the person, then they are "doing stuff" to garner that attention - hence, that makes them a "show-off".  What dictionary listing do you use that specifically lists all manifestations of a generalized characteristic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17659/discussion-between-carsmack-and-kristina-lopez).

Comment: I'd use ostentatious.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I don't think CarSmack is trolling. He's trying to be precise. A SWR is inherently asking for neither a hyponym or hypernym but as close to a synonym as possible. That means it shouldn't include lots of other things. Show-off includes quite a few other things that have nothing at all to do with dress/makeup/jewelry.

Answer (score 6):

Probably [flashy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flashy) may fit your description: ( from TFD)

> - tastelessly showy.
> - ostentatious and tasteless.

also the expression [bling-bling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Bling-bling) may fit the context:

> - (Noun) ostentatious jewellery.
> - Bling (or bling-bling) is a slang term popularized in hip hop culture, referring to flashy, ostentatious or elaborate jewelry and ornamented accessories that are carried, worn or installed, such as cell phones or tooth caps.

A woman wearing bling-bling  jewelry.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I'm looking for a noun or NP.

Comment: @user463240 'bling' isn't an NP?

Answer (score 3):

A woman all tarted up

... And yes it is a NP

Comment: I've been searching for a slangword that fits my definition and I've found your answer: "a tarted-up female".  I've also found "classy-hoochie" (A classy hoochie is a high-class woman dressed up in a slutty way)  Only I don't know whether anyone really uses that. Would you like to look it up and, if appropriate, include it?

Comment: "Hoochie," by itself is slang for prostitute or a loose woman. So is "tart." I think more people have heard of "tart," but "hoochie" is popular in "hoochie mama" and "hoochie coochie." While tarted up and classy-hoochie do not necessarily refer to a promiscuous woman, they are based on words that do, and that idea remains close if not implied. By your OP,  I am not sure you want a word that has anything to do with promiscuity. As for classy-hoochie, it remains in the realm of slang and its usage is not widespread.

Comment: No, the word I'm looking for has nothing to do with promiscuity. In my mother tongue we have a slang word for it and I am trying to find the English word that conveys exactly the same. It's not a word men would use. Women would use it when gossiping: "Did you see that ... at the meeting yesterday?  Yes, some people just don't know how ridiculous they can look."

Comment: Did you see that floozy yesterday? This comes immediately to mind. But once again, floozy can heavily imply a loose woman. I wish you well on the search for an appropriate word. Is there not a bilingual dictionary you can consult?

Comment: This is a good answer and I wish I could accept it too.

Answer (score 3):

Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) offers this note distinguishing among various similar adjectives that might be applicable:

> GAUDY, TAWDRY, GARISH, FLASHY, MERETRICIOUS mean vulgarly or cheaply showy. GAUDY implies a tasteless use of overly bright, often clashing colors or excessive ornamentation {circus performers in *gaudy* costumes}. TAWDRY applies to what is at once gaudy and cheap and sleazy {*tawdry* saloons}. GARISH describes what is distressingly or offensively bright {*garish* neon signs}. FLASHY implies an effect of brilliance quickly and easily seen to be shallow or vulgar {a *flashy* nightclub act}. MERETRICIOUS stresses falsity and may describe a tawdry show that beckons with a false allure or promise {a *meretricious* wasteland of casinos and bars}.

S.I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word* (1968) offers this discussion of the same five-word family:

> These words refer to tasteless displays of overdone finery or decoration, or to brazen, flaunting behavior. Of these words, **gaudy** is the least negative in tone, but still points to excessive use of decoration or to any sort of vividness that approaches vulgarity: ... **Flashy** is an informal substitute for *gaudy*, referring to anything deliberately chosen out of exuberantly vulgar ostentation: ...
>
> With **garish**, the emphasis is wholly on extremely distasteful ostentation and more especially of phony or trashy gimmicks: ...
>
> **Meretricious** and **tawdry** both emphasize decoration that is made of cheap or worthless materials.. With *meretricious*, the stress is on overuse, especially of phony or trashy gimmicks: ... *Tawdry* may, more simply, suggest cheapness combined with showiness in taste: ...

Of these options, *gaudy* and *flashy* seem the most applicable to the particular situation you describe.

One (gender-neutral) noun form that might fit the situation is *vulgarian*. MW's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary offers this definition:

> **vulgarian** a vulgar person

where *vulgar* may be understood to mean "lacking in cultivation, perception, or taste: COARSE" or "ostentatious or excessive in expenditure or display: PRETENTIOUS."

Answer (score 2):

You might find **Jezebel** useful.  From the Mac OS X dictionary:

> Jezebel |ˈdʒɛzəbɛl|
>   ( fl. 9th century bc ), a Phoenician princess, traditionally the great-aunt of Dido and in the Bible the wife of Ahab king of Israel. She was denounced by Elijah for introducing the worship of Baal into Israel (1 Kings 16:31, 21:5–15, 2 Kings 9:30–7). Her use of make-up was especially condemned by Puritan England.
>   • (as noun a Jezebel) a shameless or immoral woman.

The mention of make-up puts it in the right ballpark — though it might be a little OTT.

Answer (score 1):

The noun "gimcrack" might fit.

http://mnemonicdictionary.com/word/gimcrack

> (noun) ornamental objects of no great value (adj) tastelessly showy

Comment: I doubt anyone would know what was meant.

Answer (score 1):

If this person's gaudy outfits, garish make-up, and excessive jewellery are indicative of lower social class than the setting then they may be a "*parvenue*", a "*social climber*", or possibly one of the "*nouveau riche*".

If they are just naturally ostentatious or vainglorious, regardless of social class, then they may be a "*peacock*" or "*clotheshorse*".

Being more offensive, they may be "*mutton dressed as lamb*" (as others have said), or "*a duck out of water*", both of which are ageist in addition to being personally offensive.

Answer (score 0):

Some more formal semi-synonyms are **braggart and grandstander**.

http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=grandstander

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, she sounds like a real Dolly Varden, a character from Barnaby Rudge (Charles Dickins).

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably use the word 'meretricious'.

1. apparently attractive but having no real value:

"meretricious souvenirs for the tourist trade"

synonyms:   flashy, pretentious, gaudy, tawdry, trashy, garish, chintzy, Brummagem, loud, tinselly, cheap, tasteless, kitschy; More

2. archaic: relating to or characteristic of a prostitute.

Answer (score -1):

American or British?

Apparently, in the States "upper-middle class" is [based on income (and education)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_middle_class_in_the_United_States), and in the UK it's [based on birth (and education)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_middle_class#British_upper_middle_class).

I don't see your description ("gaudy outfits, garish make-up, and excessive jewelry", and "unpolished, inelegant, gauche") as upper-middle class, so I'd suggest (derogatively) "a prole", more formally "a parvenue" ... or "a foreigner" (perhaps "an American").

---

She might be upper-class though (because, *she* can wear whatever she likes): in which case, "dame", or "her ladyship", or whatever her name is (e.g. "Antonia").

But you wanted something derogatory, so "snob".

Answer (score -1):

I'd go for: **Insipid**

Wiktionary says:

> **insipid** (Flat; lacking character or definition.)
>
> Example: "*Oh my God*, what an **insipid** *WOMAN*!!!"

See link: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insipid

Comment: What about: **insipid** ?

i.e: "What an **insipid** WOMAN!!!"

Comment: Absolutely not. And *insipid* is an adjective, we talk about food being *insipid* when it is bland and without flavour. An insipid person is someone who is dull, plain and very drab.

Comment: Exactly: consider these lines...; **Word or phrase for a woman who shows up at events in gaudy outfits, garish make-up, and excessive jewelry?** --and-- **Such person is usually - but not necessarily - upper-middle class** --in line with you comment:-- **is bland and without flavour. An insipid person is someone who is dull, plain and very drab** , so, Next time she comes, the OP should Scream; "Oh my God, what an insipid WOMAN!!!"

Comment: Garish is nigh on the diametric opposite of bland - I don't see how "insipid" would be appropriate.